# Regex - match a certain number of numeric when followed by letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a string where it is 1-4 numbers, followed by a specific letter.

For example, if my string was

> 'The hardness for this rubber is 90a , the hardness for the other was
>   120a'

I want to grab the values '90a' and '120a'.

I tried `^[0-9]{0,4}[a]$` and `^([0-9]{0,4})[g]$`

Bonus points if it can match it with a space after the numbers. eg/

> 'Rubber number 1 was 98 a  , rubber number 2 was 89 a'

would match

> '98 a'

and

> '89 a'

Comment: What should happen if the string contains `12345 a` or `2345 acres` - would you still want `2345 a` to match?

Comment: no, just literally 123a or 123 a. 123abc shouldn't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem:

```
\b\d{1,4} *a\b
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b        # Start of number (or use (?<!\d) if you're not on JavaScript)
\d{1,4}   # Match 1-4 digits
[ ]*      # Match optional space(s) 
a         # Match the letter "a" 
\b        # Make sure no letter/digit follows
```

Answer (score 0):

this will match

```
(\d{1,4} \s*\w)

\d+ for one or more numbers
\s* for zero or more spaces
\w for a character
```